# Using of library under MIT license with dependency on library under MPL-2.0

Tags: mit, mpl

We want to use [MSGReader library](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader) in our project. MSGReader is open-source project under MIT license. MSGReader depends on [OpenMcdf library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenMcdf/) under Mozilla Public License 2.0.

Our project is proprietary enterprise product (commercial software, code is not disclosed).

Is using of library under MIT license with dependency on library under MPL-2.0 legal in our case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using MIT licensed and MPL-2.0 licensed dependencies in your closed-source product is legal if you meet these requirements:

- You have a copy of the MIT license in your documentation. You can precede that copy with a statement that only part of the software is covered by the MIT license. You are not required to identify which part of the software you are referring to.
- You state in your documentation that your software is using the OpenMcdf library and where people can obtain the source code for that library. There is no requirement that users can do anything with that source code in relation to your product.